# How to get frame source of an event in Java?

Tags: java, awt

I am currently working on a project and have multiple frames in it. I want to dispose the current frame user is working on if an event occurs on that particular frame

Comment: Please share some code where the problem is

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 3) Why use AWT?   See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255106/java-gui-listeners-without-awt/6255978#6255978) for many good reasons to abandon AWT using components in favor of Swing.

Comment: @sergiomse *"some code where the problem is"* is a lot longer to type than `[mcve]`. That auto-expands in a comment, to [mcve]. An MCVE is better here, in that often the OP does not know where the problem is! But if they post a short code that shows the problem for others (an MCVE), obviously it will include the code that causes the problem.